# How to set div height to fill the empty area of viewport

Tags: html, css

I want the height of the sliding-in menu to be such that it fills the viewport below the mobile-navbar div. Right now it extends beyond it and makes the menu scrollable.
Height should be: [100vh-(height of mobile-navbar)]
How can I set it to this?

I don't want to assign a fixed value as it wouldn't let it remain responsive.
And the menu should remain absolute since it needs to slide over the content underneath it.

```js
function menuSlidesIn(){
    var checkbox = document.getElementById("btnControl")
    var menu = document.getElementById("menu-options")

    if(checkbox.checked == true){
        menu.style.left = "0%"
    }
    else{
        menu.style.left = "-100%"
    }
}
```

```css
html, body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#mobile-menu{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 2em;
    margin: 0;
}
#hamburger{
    place-self: center right;
    position: relative;
}
#btnControl{
    display: none;
}
.menu-burger{
    width: 60px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #555555;
    margin: 5px 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
#menu-bar{
    position: relative;
}
#menu-options{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr) ;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: -100%;
    width: 100vw;
    max-width: 100vw;
    height: -webkit-fill-available;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: gray;
    transition: 0.5s;
    
}
#menu-options li{
    padding: 1em 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="mobile-navbar">
    <ul id="mobile-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Logo</a></li>
        <li id="hamburger">
            <input type="checkbox" id="btnControl" onclick="menuSlidesIn()"/>
            <label for="btnControl" id="label-hamburger">
            <div class="menu-burger"></div>
            <div class="menu-burger"></div>
            <div class="menu-burger"></div>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="menu-bar">
    <ul id="menu-options">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `height` using `offsetHeight` and `resize event`. Add this `JavaScript` to your code:

```
window.onresize = applyMenuHeight; // everytime page resizes, run this function

applyMenuHeight(); //run the function once at least

function applyMenuHeight() {
  var menuHeight = document.querySelector('#mobile-menu').offsetHeight; // get menu height
  document.querySelector('#menu-options').style.height = "calc(100vh - " + menuHeight + "px)"; // set the height dynamically
}
```

It will store the menu `height`, apply it for you subtracting it from `100vh` and updating it everytime the `window` is resized.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't even think of using js for it. That should fix it.

Comment: You can also achieve the same result with less code. 
min-height : calc(100vh - [height of your navbar]);

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set min-height to your menu.

```
min-height : calc(100vh - [height of your navbar]);
```

In your case

```
#menu-options{
min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
```

I have added edited your code, you can check here.
I hope it will help you.

[Check the working code here](https://codepen.io/arun-uniyal/pen/wVvEdM/)